# How can I fix a pyglet error being thrown when the first image is loaded?

Tags: python, windows, opengl, pyglet

I'm running an emergency Robotics programming course remotely for school kids stuck at home who were supposed to be attending an Easter Science school.  I'm using a homegrown Python robot simulator which I know works fine on most computers.  One of the students can't get it to work.  She is using Windows 10, but is not an experienced programmer nor particularly familiar with computers and so I've not managed to get more details from her.

The simulator uses pyglet for its visualisation.  The first time the program tries to load an image on her system using

`pyglet.resource.image("robot/rover.png")`

It throws the error

`pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: b'invalid value`

This is because of an error in line 105 of pyglet\gl\lib.py, raised by line 1559 in pyglet\image__init.py (a call to GlTexImage2D) which tracks back to an error in line 554 of pyglet\resource.py (sorry for no full trace, she's sent me a screenshot).  It looks like a problem with pyglet's handling of textures in OpenGL.

Obviously my options for debugging this through the computer screen are limited.  But I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this error before and has an idea of a quick fix that might sort it out.

[image: Screenshot sent by student]

Comment: Could you attach the screenshot that was given to you? At least the area of the console where this error occurs?

Comment: I've added the screenshot.  NB.  I've fixed the warning that were being thrown relating to the "None" literal.

Comment: Check, it feels like you've attached a thumbnail tho. Becaus the image is extremely pixelated, or is this the original quality? hehe